# Convert joomla 1.5 to 2.5 with whole site and also with virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

How i convert my current website of joomla1.5 to joomla2.5

please anyone help me

When i using jUploader it is only allow to convert joomla1.5.18 to 1.7 but i need joomla2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thre is a lot of documentation out there on how to convert Joomla 1.5 sites to Joomla 2.5.

You need to use an extension such as [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) to upgrade your site to 2.5.
Please bare in mine that this will update your database tables and core extensions such as `com_content`, `mod_login` etc. This will **not** upgrade 3rd party extensions that you have found from the Joomla Extensions Directory. You will need to go back to whereever you downloaded these extensions from and see if there is a Joomla 2.5 compatible version of them, and install them, else you'll need to look for an alternative.

Seeing as you have waited all the way till now, you might be best off upgrading again to Joomla 3.x. Even though this it eh short term release, it is the way forward, will save what could be another time consuming upgrade in the future.

Oh and as always recommended, please make sure you take a backup of your site before the upgrade.

Hope this helps